# HashSet not removing all duplicate entries

Tags: java, eclipse, guava

I am attempting to use a HashSet to make sure data I read in from a .txt file are unique.

Below is the sample data;

```
999990  bummer
999990  bummer
999990  bummer
999990  bummer
99999   bummer
999990  bummerr
```

Which is read in using Java.io.File and Java.util.Scanner and stored as an Object of Term as such;

Reading in terms;

```
while (rawTerms.hasNextLine()){
    String[] tokens = rawTerms.nextLine().trim().split(delimiter);
    if (tokens.length == 2) {               
        uniqueSet.add(new Term(Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]), tokens[1])); //add the term to set
    }
    else {
      rawTerms.close();
      throw new Exception("Invalid member length: "+ tokens.length);
    }           
}

allTerms = new ArrayList<>(uniqueSet); //Covert set into an ArrayList
```

Term class using Guava;

```
public Term(double weight, String theTerm){
    this.weight = weight;
    this.theTerm = theTerm;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Term){
        final Term other = (Term) obj;
        return Objects.equal(this.weight, other.weight)
                && Objects.equal(this.theTerm, other.theTerm);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return toStringHelper(this).addValue(weight)
            .addValue(theTerm).toString();

}

@Override  
public int hashCode() {  
    return Objects.hashCode(this.weight, this.theTerm);  
}
```

However, when I run a test to check the size of the array the entries are stored in, I get 3 entries instead of 1 which I am aiming for. I would like any new entry with either the same weight or term as previously added entries to be considered a duplicate.

All help is appreciated!

Matt

Comment: What is `uniqueSet`?

Comment: Your formatting is very ... erratic. Please your autoformat in your IDE before posting; and ensure that your formatting is consistent. Also note that Egyptian brackets are preferred for Java. Finally, if you have a `return` you have no need for an `else`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've never been to Egypt, nor do I import their brackets, but I've been programming for ages now.  Kidding aside, I think curly brackets would invoke the desired idea in other's minds before Egyptian ones. :)

Comment: Egyptian brackets _are_ curly brackets. It's about their placement.

Comment: @EdwinBuck curly brackets are the type of brackets (`{}`). [Egyptian brackets](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) (3 in the link) are a style of formatting code blocks, preferred in Java over [K&R C style brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you for the explanation, but this is very new slang.  There's also different definitions for the same item.  Sounds like someone's trying to smith a word, and according to http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html Egyptian brackets are K&R style brackets.  I'd say we already have K&R brackets to describe them.

Comment: @EdwinBuck K&R uses both Egyptian and braces on their own line. It's a mixed style.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you for your feedback on my formatting. Belphegor has been kind enough to help make it more readable.

Comment: @talex uniqueSet is the name I have given to my HashSet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I would like any new entry with either the same weight or term as previously added entries to be considered a duplicate.

That's not how equality works. Equality has to be *transitive* - so if `x.equals(y)` returns true, and `y.equals(z)` returns true, then `x.equals(z)` has to return true.

That's not the case in your desired relation.

Note that it's also not what your `equals` method checks at the moment:

```
return Objects.equal(this.weight, other.weight)
    && Objects.equal(this.theTerm, other.theTerm);
```

That only returns true if the weight *and* term match, which is normal for an equality relation. That's why you're getting three entries in your set - because when viewed in that way, you *do* have three distinct enties.

Fundamentally, `HashSet` and all the other collections dealing with equality won't help you in a simple way. You'll need to have three separate collections:

- A set of weights
- A set of terms
- A set (or list) of entries.

If the entry you're considering has a weight in the set of weights *or* a term in the set of terms, you should skip it - otherwise, you should add an entry to each of the three collections.

Comment: The set of entries can then become a simple list.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Indeed. I wasn't sure whether to add that or not... will edit slightly.

Comment: I mean, since there is no custom equality defined on the `Term` anymore, each instance is in its own equality class. Therefore a set is nothing but overhead.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Well, the OP *may* want to keep the equality anyway, and they *may* want to keep it as a set to emphasize that ordering is irrelevant.

Comment: The static type can be `Collection` to show there are no ordering semantics implied. But... let's not descend into this.

Answer (score 6):

Considering the implementation of `hashCode` (and `equals`) in the `Term` class, you **should** expect 3 entries, corresponding to the pairs involved:

```
999990  bummer
99999   bummer
999990  bummerr
```

Both `hashCode` and `equals` evaluate both properties of the pair, namely the `weight` `double` and the `theTerm` `String`.

The set will evaluate inequality by comparing hash codes, which will be different for the 3 elements listed above.

Comment: The question state that TS have duplicates. Your answer doesn't explain why it is happens.

Comment: It doesn't answer what the OP is trying to achieve though: "I would like any new entry with either the same weight or term as previously added entries to be considered a duplicate."

Comment: I am now aware that I should expect 3 entries. However, my aim is for 1 unique entry. Perhaps what @JonSkeet suggested below (using separate collections for each) will solve my issue?

Comment: @MathanaSreedaran Jon Skeet's answers are certainly worth checking everytime. If I have to add anything here is: think of the criteria you need for the entries to be unique. For instance, the "difference" between `999990` and `99999` or `bummer` and `bummerr`. Since this can be hardly generalized, you might need to implement your own collection type that iterates the previous entries and checks each term of the pair against the terms of the pair you are trying to add. This may become very inefficient in terms of performance though.